# How do multiple developers use the same queue for development?

Tags: message-queue, amazon-sqs

We use SQS for queueing use-cases in our company. All developers connect to the same queue for local development. If we're producing some messages for testing in local development, it can happen that the message is consumed on other person's locally running consumer, if that person has the app running at the same time.

How do you make sure that messages produced by one  person don't end up getting lost by consumption on other person's locally running consumer. Is using different different queues for each person the only solution? Wondering what is standard followed to avoid this in the industry?

Answer (score 0):

This is very open-ended IMO. Would recommend adding some context as to how you're using SQS.

But from what I could understand:
Yes, I would recommend creating queues per "developer"

OR

Although not elegant, you can maybe add an SQS message attribute (this is metadata other than message body) with a developer's username.
And each developer should then only process a message if it's meant for them. Arguably, you could also add a flag in the message itself, but, I am not sure about the constraints on your message format. Message attributes are meant to be used for these situations, where you want to know if you really need to process a message before even parsing the message body.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-metadata.html#sqs-message-attributes

But you'll have to increase the maxReceives to a high number (so that message does not move to dead letter queue, if you have configured one). This is not exhaustive, it will just decrease the chances of your messages being deleted by someone else. Because if say, 10 people read the message and did not delete it because username was not their username, and maxReceives is 8, it will still move to DLQ and cause unnecessary confusion.

Comment: A Queue for each developer might become harder to maintain. Using developer's username as attribute seems like a very good strategy. Will explore that.